# I need to be able to remove all leading letters from user input for var custint = document.getElementById("custint").value;

Tags: replace, var, getelementbyid

The input might contain no letters, but could contain two or more letters.I only need the information beginning with the first number for the output. There will be forward slashes between numbers that I do not want to remove.

Input might be something like Gi1/3, or Eth2/2, or maybe even GigabitInterface0/0/1/2

I currently have the following, but it only works if there are no more than two leading letters, and I don't know how many might be entered by the user:

var custint = document.getElementById("custint").value;
custint = custint.replace(/[^\d,]/,''); <- only removes the first letter
custint = custint.replace(/[^\d,]/,''); <- so I added it again for the second letter

Input as 2/2 or ETh2/2 would result in Output like this:

- "\r\ninterface Ethernet" + custint
  which produces this: "interface Ethernet2/2"

Comment: I figured out a method that works for my needs: custint = custint.replace(/[^0-9\W]/g,'');